# How to configure multiple sites with same URL on Nginx

Tags: nginx, slim, nginx-location, nginx-config

I am trying to have 2 websites running on the same adress,

I want everything request on `my.website.com/test_slim` and every `my.website.com/test_slim/anything/following` to be directed on `/var/www/html/test_slim/src/public/index.php`.

I want everything else (`my.website.com/`, `my.website.com/foo`, `my.website.com/bar/baz` ...) to be served as normal PHP files in `/var/www/html/whatever/file/according/to/url/index.php`

Fow now, this are my server configurations :

In `/etc/nginx/site-enabled/my-default`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

In `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test_slim`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    index index.php;
    error_log /var/www/html/test_slim/error.log;
    access_log /var/www/html/test_slim/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/test_slim/src/public;

    location /test_slim/ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

But what I actually get is :

- Request on `localhost/` execute `/var/www/html/index.html` as wanted.
- Request on `localhost/toto` execute `/var/www/html/toto/index.html` as wanted.
- Request on `localhost/test_slim` **downloads** the `/var/www/html/test_slim/src/public/index.pxp`
- Request on `localhost/test_slim/hello` returns us a Nginx error page (404 if `hello` folder doesn't exist, 403 if it does).
- Request on `localhost/test_slim/src/public/` exectute the `/var/www/html/test_slim/src/public/index.php` file.

Comment: `//localhost/` and `//localhost/test_slim` are the same server and will use the same `server` block. You currently have two `server` blocks with the same `server_name` which is an error and will probably prevent Nginx from restarting. Test your configuration using `nginx -t`

Comment: Oh ! Ok, I understand now.
Thanks a lot !! My website works now.